# How to play preroll?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-video-player

I want to play preroll ad (Just like you tube) before playing any video live streaming in my app. Right now i am able to play video using URL through streaming but not able to find any way to play preroll please some one help me to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just provide a ArrayList of videoUrls for your media player. Use the OnCompletionListener interface and play the next (none-preroll) video when the preroll has been completed. From what Ive understood you can't feed the Android media player a list of urls, you have to setDataSource for each video.

```
//Starting the mediaplayer
private void playVideo() {
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(videoUrlList.get(playlistPosition));
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();     
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {  
//Look if the list has more videos
if (playlistPosition < videoUrlList.size() - 1) {
playlistPosition++;

if(mediaPlayer != null)
mediaPlayer.reset();

playVideo();
}else{
//If no more videos, quit MoviePlayer Activity
finish();
}
```

}

Comment: I just did, mark it as an answer if you think it points you in the right direction.

Comment: the answer is wrong , please don't mark for wrong answers